# Net::XMPP Perl module: Can this be used to check for chat messages on server?

Tags: perl, xmpp

I can now connect to my jabber server using the perl module Net::XMPP. Now I would like to know: Is it possible to monitor the server for incoming chat messages (NOT email messages) and act accordingly if one is recieved?

The basic code I currently have is:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::XMPP;

my $con = new Net::XMPP::Client(); 

my $status = $con->Connect(  
hostname => 'hostnamepart',  
connectiontype => 'tcpip',  
tls => 1,
ssl_ca_path =>'path for cert');
die('ERROR: XMPP connection failed') if ! defined($status);
```

The $status variable returns 1 when I run the code above which I assume means that I connected ok. However, now I am stuck! I have looked through the online documentation on the metacpan.org website for Net::XMPP but cannot figure out if it's even possible to do what I want. Any help appreciated.

Comment: See the examples in the [`examples`](https://metacpan.org/source/DAPATRICK/Net-XMPP-1.05/examples) folder. Seems like you have to use `$con->SetCallBacks()`

Comment: Many thanks Håkon, I'll take a look and see if I can come up with something

Comment: OK, ALMOST there...I have now used the code client.pl in the examples folder. Everythig works fine until right at the end where I try and check for a Process (line containing while(defined($Connection->Process())) { }   ) However the code gives the following error that I have no idea how to resolve "There was an error in the last call to Process that you did not check for and
handle.  You should always check the output of the Process call.  If it was
undef then there was a fatal error that you need to check.  There is an error
in your program at client.pl line x."